# html5 Image upload

Tags: image, html, input, upload

I'm trying to make a VERY simple image uploader in html5.

```
<input type="file" multiple=""/>
```

All I would like  to do is display what is uploaded without using PhP or anything. Could I use code similar to this?

```
<img src="WHATEVER WAS UPLOADED"/>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256620/can-i-preview-the-image-file-who-uploaded-by-user-in-the-browser

Answer (score 5):

i found

```
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/
```

rather helpful.

if you dont want to push the image to some server ( i assume this from your question ), you can just update the image locally :

```
<style>
  .thumb {
    height: 75px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
    }
 </style>

<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>

<script>
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

   // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
   for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

     // Only process image files.
     if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
       continue;
     }

     var reader = new FileReader();

     // Closure to capture the file information.
     reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
       return function(e) {
          // Render thumbnail.
          var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                        '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
          document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
    };
      })(f);

      // Read in the image file as a data URL.
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);

 </script>
```

or somesuch.

Comment: Could you modify this for accepting a single image only (ie not multiple images) and remove the loop treatment?  `files` is used in several places and i'm not sure whether it is referring to the variable `files` or the id `files` or the name `files` so I haven't been able to make that modification.

Comment: This seems to work for a single image upload and preview and is based off the above code http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/4n8HW/

Comment: Further explanation and more code can be found from this link: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Answer (score 0):

You could archive this with HTML5 File Api.

Following tutorial should get you started: [Reading local files in JavaScript](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

Comment: but reading local files tutorial uses filereader,that doesnot work for IE. It works for the rest of browsers [check here](http://caniuse.com/filereader)