# How to upload an image to server on change

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery, gd, jcrop

I have an input tag like

```
<form id="myForm">
<!-- has lots of inputs above like username password etc -->
<input type="file" id="user_photo" name="user_photo" tabindex="6" size="6" class="" accept="jpeg|png|jpg|gif|PNG|JPEG|GIF|JPG" >
```

OnChange, I would want to upload an image through AJAX and save it in server. After saving, it should display in a preview div where I can use jCrop to crop as user wishes and save it again to the server (after cropping) when user clicks submit button.

If you have a better method please tell me.

inshort, I just want to trigger an ajax post request with the file contents and save it into my uploads folder without sending the rest of the form elements.

I use codeigniter. I have tried fileuploader by valum.. didnt give me the result.

Comment: have you tried anything...if yes please show the code...

Comment: @Dk-Macadamia : I tried using valum's plugin [here](https://github.com/Valums-File-Uploader/file-uploader)

Comment: but didnt work/confused me a lot. so dropped it. I would edit and put the entire form if u want.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was stolen from here: [Can i preview the image file who uploaded by user in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256620/can-i-preview-the-image-file-who-uploaded-by-user-in-the-browser)

1. Use the `HTML5 File Api` to load the image client side.
2. Then use jCrop at the after loading the image into a tag.
3. Then (I'm assuming) use jCrops `onRelease` method to do the Ajax call.
4. That way its only one ajax call, and its already modified

```html
<img id="preview" src="placeholder.png" height="100px" width="100px" />
<input type="file" name="image" onchange="previewImage(this)" accept="image/*"/>
<script type="text/javascript">      
 function previewImage(input) {
    var preview = document.getElementById('preview');
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) {
        preview.setAttribute('src', e.target.result);
         $('#preview').Jcrop({
            onRelease: yourAjaxFunctionToSubmitToServer
         });
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    } else {
      preview.setAttribute('src', 'placeholder.png');
    }
  }
</script>
```

Obviously this will need to be modified a bit to suit your needs, but you get the idea.